# How to loop through an array of objects using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic app that loads data from firebase. In this case I have a .factory called NoteStore that reads a specific table in firebase (eg "lakes").

```
{
  "lake": {   
     "one": {
        "bio": "xxxx",
        "shortname": "xxxx",
        "name": "xxxxx",
        "reknown": "xxxx",
        "image":"xxxxx"
    },
    "two": {
        "bio": "xxxx",
        "shortname": "xxxx",
        "name": "xxxxx",
        "reknown": "xxxx",
        "image":"xxxxx"
    }

  } 
}
```

This is the .factory code that reads from firebase:

```
 //get all lake activites
 getAllLakes: function(){
   return $firebaseArray(ref.child('lake'));
 },

//get individual lake activites
 getLake: function(lakeId){
  return $firebaseObject(ref.child('lake').child(lakeId));
}
```

My app Controller then gets the data through the NoteStore and calling a function "getAllLakes():

```
app.controller('LakeActivitiesListController', function($scope, NoteStore,              $localStorage) {
$scope.alllakes = NoteStore.getAllLakes();
}
```

The main problem is that I want to access individual objects from the "lake" table in firebase so that I can be able to store them in localStorage.

This then displays array of objects as below:
[image: array of objects hidden]

When I just create an object as shown below and save to localStorage, it works fine, as shown in the image below.

```
var myObj = [
{
  name: 'james',
  title:'doctor'

},
{
  name: 'jojo',
  title:'doctor'

}
];
console.log(myObj);


//
window.localStorage['lakes'] = JSON.stringify(myObj);

$scope.data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('lakes'));
```

### [image: stored obj in localStorage]

[image: this works fine]

I am working on my college project that is overdue. Please help. All I want is to be able to access an array that contains objects from firebase so that I can store them in localStorage.
Please.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far? So that we better understand your problem?

Comment: Hi, I tried these options:  `  $scope.storeData = function(){
         $localStorage.data = $scope.alllakes;
     }
     
    //load data
   $scope.loadData = function(){
       $scope.data =  $localStorage.data;
   }
   
   $scope.doRefresh =function() {
         $scope.loadData();
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

   }`  and also `var lakeData = alllakes.getAllLakes();
 
   var data = {};
   data = lakeData;
   
 for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var obj = data[i];
  console.log(obj);
 }
`

Comment: Can you post the result from the firebase query?

Comment: @ Evans Dianga. I have data pulled from firebase fine and I also have ng-repeat in my index.html that does data binding fine and displays all the fields from firebase table on the app. [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/37d9585.png)

Answer (score 6):

[angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) is the way, here is an example:

**Example with array of objects iteration:**

```
var array_of_objects = [{name: 'Jimi', gender: 'male'},{name: 'Peter', gender: 'male'},{name: 'Bob', gender: 'male'}];

angular.forEach(array_of_objects, function(item, index) {
  console.log(item, index);
});
```

**Example with object iteration:**

```
var my_object = {name: 'Jimi', gender: 'male', age: '25'};

angular.forEach(my_object, function(value, key) {
  console.log(value, key);
});
```

In your case you want to make an `angular.forEach` on `$scope.alllakes` and then push the object that you want in the storage

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, that you have an object not an array. You can loop through the different members of you object with

```
for(var propertyName in myObject) {
   // propertyName is what you want
   // you can get the value like this: myObject[propertyName]
}
```